# Re-sizing an object's scale with a condition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I have a simple cube whose **local scale** I would like to change, according to the following script.

I do not want the size to get smaller than a certain amount, so I have put in an `if` loop to ensure this.

If the user does not specify minimum scale values, then the starting scale values are considered as the red line. There is an option (checkbox) to decide this.

However, I wonder if there is a neater way of ding this, rather than such a clunky loop going through the 3 values?

This works of course. When I run the scene and keep moving the camera back and forth, the cube grows/shrinks accordingly and never gets smaller than either the starting size (if the box is not ticked) or the specified minimum scale (if the box is ticked) about I wonder if this can be done concisely?

```
/// <summary>
/// Updates the size/scale of an object as the user
/// (i.e. the hololens camera) moves back and forth.
/// This script should be attached to the game object.
/// </summary>
public class ObjectScaler : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// In the Inspector panel, drag and drop the
    /// intended object that needs to be re-sized.
    /// </summary>
    public GameObject _renderCamera;

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the minimum size that specifies
    /// the object should not get smaller than this.
    /// When you put this script on an object, it takes
    /// the actual starting size of the object, but this way,
    /// you can even specify a different size as a minimum.
    /// </summary>
    public float _minXScale;
    public float _minYScale;
    public float _minZScale;

    /// <summary>
    /// Should I use the defined minimm size, or should I assume
    /// the actual starting object size is the minimm size?
    /// If you check it, you have to provide a float for size.
    /// If you leave it unchecked, the real size of the object
    /// at start-up is taken as the minimum size.
    /// </summary>
    public bool _useTheseMinScales;

    /// <summary>
    /// The starting scale of the object at start-up;
    /// whether it is the actual object's scale or whether
    /// it is formed by _minXScale,_minYScale,_minZScale values.
    /// </summary>
    private Vector3 _startingScale;

    /// <summary>
    /// The distance between the object and holocam at start-up.
    /// </summary>
    private float _startingDistance;

    /// <summary>
    /// Current constantly-updated distance between
    /// the object and holocam at any given moment.
    /// </summary>
    private float _currentDistance;


    void Start()
    {
        var objectTransformPos = this.transform.position;
        var cameraTransformPos = _renderCamera.transform.position;
        _startingDistance = Vector3.Distance(cameraTransformPos, objectTransformPos);
        _startingScale = this.transform.localScale;
    }


    void LateUpdate()
    {
        _currentDistance = Vector3.Distance(_renderCamera.transform.position, this.transform.position);

        if (_useTheseMinScales)
        {
            if ( (_startingScale.x * (_currentDistance / _startingDistance) >= _minXScale) &&
                 (_startingScale.y * (_currentDistance / _startingDistance) >= _minYScale) &&
                 (_startingScale.z * (_currentDistance / _startingDistance) >= _minZScale) )
            {
                this.transform.localScale = _startingScale * (_currentDistance / _startingDistance);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ( (_startingScale.x * (_currentDistance / _startingDistance) >= _startingScale.x) && 
                 (_startingScale.y * (_currentDistance / _startingDistance) >= _startingScale.y) && 
                 (_startingScale.z * (_currentDistance / _startingDistance) >= _startingScale.z) )
            {
                this.transform.localScale = _startingScale * (_currentDistance / _startingDistance);
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So at the beginnig your camera distance is fixed ? if so we can say your scale is somehow relevant to distance. Lets say distance is 10. And your object scale is 10. And your object scale will never go down 10. But your camera distance can ? So do your calculation on your distance. If your distance is less than 10, do not do scaling ?

Comment: Correct! At the beginning, it is all fixed. Then, I run the scene and move the camera back and forth. The cube size changes smoothly and when the camera goes beyond the cube (to its other side) the same thing happens, so all works as I want it, but I worry about the loop efficiency, etc... and whether there would be a succinct way of formulating my x,y,z checks.

Comment: Can't come up with another thing right now beside keep checking the position or scale.

Comment: If you want to keep size-checking, you should use `&&` instead of `&`, because `&` runs every check even if the first one returns `false`. `&&` stops checking if it detects a check returning `false

Comment: @Joshua I have read and answered 2 of your recent posts; one thing that sticks out for me is that you trying to apply your logic to situations where you do not understand the parameters. Before manipulating objects try to read the unity manual what the parameters of that object are. And in which context they operate.

Comment: @JeroenDeClercq I do go through the unity manual beforehand to learn about the parameters for the first time, etc... but obviously not everyone always understands everything perfectly at the beginning, which is why people try to do stuff and then ask questions on forums. But thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Rafiwui  Thanks a lot for this!  I did not notice it at all.  Cheers

Comment: @Joshua And to avoid creating (float division is expensive) and checking three values check the answer below ;)

Comment: @Rafiwui Many thanks. That is certainly a smart idea, but this sub-task (of a HoloLens project) involves using a minimum scale, so I have to conform to that unfortunately. But your idea is definitely a simple effective way of achieving the behavior while avoiding the craetion and checking of 3 values. Thank you.

Comment: If you have a min and max value of the scale and then a min and a max distance the camera can go from the Object, I have an awesome solution that doesn't even require an `if` statement. If you don't know these then forget it as I have nothing.

Comment: @Programmer I have edited it a bit to include minimum values. Please tell me about your awesome solution if it can be applied to this problem. Thanks. Basically, I wanna make sure as the holo user walks back, the object grows and as they approach, the object shrinks, but not smaller than a certain size that the user can define in the Inspector... Thanks

Comment: It's better to have the min scale as Vector3 which contains x,y,z. Also the max scale of the object should also be Vector3. This will prevent having many floats. For the min and max distance, that should just be 2 floats. one for min and another one for max. So it should be something like this: `Vector3 minScale = ....` then `Vector3 maxScale = ....`.... And `float minDistance = ...` then `float maxDistance = ...` I will then use these to calculate the scale that's never < or > the min, max scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't check on the size, but check the distance:
Your `x/y/zSize` is only smaller then your `_startingScale` when `_startingDistance > _currentDistance`.
So a solution would look like the following:

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    _currentDistance = Vector3.Distance(_renderCamera.transform.position, this.transform.position);

    float scaleFactor = _currentDistance / _startingDistance;
    if (_useTheseMinScales)
    {
        if ( (_startingScale.x * scaleFactor >= _minXScale) &&
             (_startingScale.y * scaleFactor >= _minYScale) &&
             (_startingScale.z * scaleFactor >= _minZScale) )
        {
            this.transform.localScale = _startingScale * scaleFactor;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (_startingDistance > _currentDistance)
        {
            this.transform.localScale = _startingScale * scaleFactor;
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Due to its simplicity, I find this solution quite elegant, but I have to have public scales, so the user can specify his minimum size. I have edited my post a bit to include the latest I have. It does the job, but I wonder if i can be improved?

Comment: Made some changes so the performance should be maximized (at least as far as my c# knowledge goes xD)

Comment: Thank you! The `else` part does not quite work the way I want, so I left my checks in, but I should have thought of `scaleFactor` before!

Comment: Strange. Try `scaleFactor > 1.0f` instead of `_startingDistance > _currentDistance` and use Debug.Log to check what is executed and what values are given.